# How to find current UIViewController in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am using the [Facebook Auth SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginManager/), with a Xamarin Forms C# [example](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/blob/master/XamarinSamples/DynamoDB/). However, the Facebook SDK has depreciated the method and replaced it with one which adds a `fromViewController` variable into the constructors. I am not particularly comfortable with the concept of ViewControllers in Xamarin, or indeed with this code as it is from a sample, so is there a way to gauge the current ViewController?

I have seen a few .net examples e.g. `NSArray *viewContrlls=[[self navigationController] viewControllers];[viewContrlls lastObject];` However, this approach doesn't seem to work with Xamarin, as `self` doesn't contain definitions for navigationControllers.

Alternatively, is there any way of easily working out which variable my current ViewController is sotored in, using the sample code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best way to do this is to pass in a reference to the ViewController that is calling the Auth method.

However, you can also try this approach (courtesy of AdamKemp on the [Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24689/how-to-acces-the-current-view-uiviewcontroller-from-an-external-service))

```
var window= UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
var vc = window.RootViewController;
while (vc.PresentedViewController != null)
{
    vc = vc.PresentedViewController;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll try this now! Here is the bit that has confused me slighty. In the sample, you see the `LoginPage()` which just has a button, but the Facebook button is an empty class, which in the ios project has some definitions in `FacebookButtonRenderer.cs`, Which ViewController is active during my PopUp of the facebook login screen.

Answer (score 26):

**Update**
This method has become a bit more complex in order to support newer iOS versions in race conditions. This is the new version of the utility with some improvements:

```
public static UIViewController? GetTopViewController()
{
    var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.GetKeyWindow();
    var vc = window?.RootViewController;
    while (vc is { PresentedViewController: { } })
        vc = vc.PresentedViewController;

    if (vc is UINavigationController { ViewControllers: { } } navController) 
        vc = navController.ViewControllers.Last();

    return vc;
}

public static UIWindow? GetKeyWindow(this UIApplication application)
{
    if (!UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0)) 
        return application.KeyWindow; // deprecated in iOS 13
    
    var window = application
        .ConnectedScenes
        .ToArray()
        .OfType<UIWindowScene>()
        .SelectMany(scene => scene.Windows)
        .FirstOrDefault(window => window.IsKeyWindow);

    return window;
}
```

---

**Old answer**

The accepted answer won´t give you the current view controller if it´s in the stack of a parent `UINavigationController`, so I came up with the following:

```
public static UIViewController GetTopViewController()
{
    var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
    var vc = window.RootViewController;
    while (vc.PresentedViewController != null)
        vc = vc.PresentedViewController;

    if (vc is UINavigationController navController)
        vc = navController.ViewControllers.Last();

    return vc;
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: there is no such method: navController.ViewControllers.Last()

Comment: @Tertium you need to add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: i am on C#7.1 any alternative of your code recursive condition is not supported on C# 7.1 as suggested by compiler in my case

Comment: @JayBhatia - do `while (vc.PresentedViewController != null)`, like in the old answer. [No idea why xleon changed to the other syntax, which is less clear in this case.]

Comment: The second usage becomes `if (vc is UINavigationController navController && navController.ViewControllers.Any())`