# MAUI .NullReferenceException (Native iOS QLPreviewController)

Tags: .net-6.0, maui, qlpreviewcontroller, uidocumentinteractioncontroller

I am having a problem running after through the QLPreviewController interface.

```
view.PushViewController(previewController, true);
```

QLPreviewController starts up and displays what it should. At this point,

```
UIApplication.Main(args, null, typeof(AppDelegate));
```

throws an error

```
{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.NavigationRenderer.SecondaryToolbar.LayoutToolbarItems(NFloat toolbarWidth, NFloat toolbarHeight, NFloat padding)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.NavigationRenderer.SecondaryToolbar.LayoutSubviews()
at UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(Int32 argc, String\[\] argv, IntPtr principalClassName, IntPtr delegateClassName)
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main(String\[\] args, Type principalClass, Type delegateClass)
at MAUISample.Program.Main(String\[\] args) in ...MAUISampleProject}
```

Does anyone know how to fix it or what I might be doing wrong ?

Greetings Matlas

I also tried to open the pdf file through UIDocumentInteractionController. The problem looks the same the file opens but the same error is thrown.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Could you provide some code about your use of QLPreviewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing this question solved the issue for me for MAUI iOS .NET 8.0.1: [How to find current UIViewController in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582728/how-to-find-current-uiviewcontroller-in-xamarin)

```
public async Task<string> SaveFileAsync(byte[] content, string localFilename)
{
   string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
   string filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilename);
   await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(filePath, content); // writes to local storage
   return filePath;
}

public void OpenPdf(string filePath)
{
    string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    var PreviewController = UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromFilename(filePath));
    var vc = GetTopViewController();
    PreviewController.Delegate = new PDFViewer(vc);
    PreviewController.PresentPreview(true);
}

public static UIViewController GetTopViewController()
{
    var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
    var vc = window.RootViewController;
    while (vc.PresentedViewController != null)
        vc = vc.PresentedViewController;
    if (vc is UINavigationController navController)
        vc = navController.ViewControllers.Last();
    return vc;
}

public class PDFViewer : UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate
{
    UIViewController ownerVC;

    public PDFViewer(UIViewController vc)
    {
        ownerVC = vc;
    }

    public override UIViewController ViewControllerForPreview(UIDocumentInteractionController controller)
    {
        return ownerVC;
    }

    public override UIView ViewForPreview(UIDocumentInteractionController controller)
    {
        return ownerVC?.View ?? new UIView();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and discovered that the root cause was actually in appshell.xml.cs I had to step through the debugger using step into.  I would have thought that the exception would have been thrown in appshell and lead me directly there but I didn't discover this until I followed the code by stepping into everything.  The problem is related to my code but the exception location is misleading or it was for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).